# Toggle front/back cameras

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera

Following my previous question, I've made a lot of changes to my code which has bought up a new set of questions which is why I decided to create a new question instead of following the previous.

I'm currently playing around with Swift development where I'm trying to make a basic application which displays the camera within a `UIImageview`.

I am using the `AVFoundation` framework.

So far, I've been able to set up the front facing camera on load. My question is, how would I go about implemented the ability to toggle the camera upon a button click?

I firstly inititialise instances:

```
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
var sessionOutputSetting = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG])
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
```

I also created a toggle bool:

```
// Bool to manage camera toggle. False = front-face (default)
var toggle = false
```

In the `viewWillApear` I call `pickCamera` function which checks the value of toggle and creates a device descovery session:

```
func pickCamera(which: Bool) {
    if (which == true) {
        let deviceDescovery = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.back)

        startCamera(deviceDesc: deviceDescovery!)
        toggle = true;

    } else if (which == false) {
        let deviceDescovery = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInTelephotoCamera, AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)

        startCamera(deviceDesc: deviceDescovery!)
        toggle = false;

    }
}
```

The `startCamera` function then creates and sets the captureSession and adds to the parent layer to display:

```
func startCamera(deviceDesc: AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession) {
    for device in (deviceDesc.devices)! {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back) {
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)

                    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput)) {
                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Exception")
            }
        } else if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front) {
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {
                    captureSession.addInput(input)

                    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput)) {
                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Exception")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've also added a button with an action:

```
@IBAction func toggleCamera(_ sender: Any) {
    if (toggle == false) {
        print("Changing to back camera")
        previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        toggle = true;
        pickCamera(which: true)

    } else if (toggle == true) {
        print("Changing to front camera")
        previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        toggle = false;
        pickCamera(which: false)
    }
}
```

The toggle method is supposed to clear the current view and call the `pickCamera` method which should create a new instance of the alternative camera.

Although for some reason, this is not working. I'm guessing it's something to do with not properly clearing the previous view/adding the new view correctly but again i'm unsure.

Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem and please ask if i'm missing information or have not explained myself properly.

**Update**
Finally fixed. The problem lied with not stopping the current `captureSession` before creating a new `captureSession`.

To fix this, I updated the `toggleCamera` function to include:

```
let currentCameraInput: AVCaptureInput = captureSession.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureInput
```

For anyone interested in the code, look [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd1aa6b5c8d24e5469e6916908918a2c)

Comment: Please do not delete questions to post the same question again. Better edit the original question.

Comment: Apologies @shallowThought. I'll take that on board in the future. If you could take a look at the issue I would be greatly thankful.

Comment: I followed your previous comments and externalised into a seperate function, but I seem to get an issue regarding to the check to see if input can be added.

Comment: `toggleCamera()` is stubbed (has no implementation).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Are you able to explain? I thought I'd only need `toggleCamera()` to call `pickCamera()` which should do all the work?

Comment: Sorry, please see the `toggleCamera()` method within the question, the git is outdated. I will update the git now.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f0097b295d3b7adf3c0e2ea154c7e8df